# How do I use jquery to create an array of my images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How can I use jquery to loop though my images & create an array using the "title" & "src" values?

This is my list of images:

```
<div id="myImages">
  <img data-title="1" src="1.jpg" alt="">
  <img data-title="2" src="2.jpg" alt="">
  <img data-title="3" src="3.jpg" alt="">
  <img data-title="4" src="4.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

This is what I need my array to be:

```
[ { "title" : "1", "image" : "1.jpg", }, { "title" : "2", "image" : "2.jpg", }, { "title" : "3", "image" : "3.jpg", }, { "title" : "4", "image" : "4.jpg", } ]
```

Comment: Just fyi, an array of arrays looks like this: `[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[2,34,55]]`, not `[{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{2,34,55}]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) convert a set of dom elements to a different representation

```
var array = $('#myImages img').map(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    return {
        title: $this.data('title'),
        image: $this.attr('src')
    }
}).get();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SaF7K/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var data = [];

$('#myImages img').each(function() {
    var img = {title: $(this).data('title'), image: $(this).attr('src')};
    data[data.length] = img;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var imageArray = [];
$('#myImages img').each(function() {
  imageArray.push({title: $(this).data('title'), image: $(this).attr('src')});
});
```